# Rotating sprite moves the sprite from it's original location

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

I'm doing a simple rotation on a sprite but there's a weird behavior where the sprite does not rotate around it's top left. I think I'm rotating along the top left of the test class instead of the sprite child. I would like to rotate the rectangle around it's top left corner (kinda like a clock hand). The code is pretty short so I'll let the code + pictures explain my problem:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        public function test()
        {
            var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            mySprite.graphics.drawRect(100,100,6,120);
            mySprite.graphics.endFill();
            this.addChild(mySprite);
            mySprite.rotation = 45;
        }

    }
}
```

Seems too simple to screw up, well here are the results. The red line is over the home key for reference. First pic I set `mySprite.rotation=0` and second is the code shown above:
[image: http://i56.tinypic.com/a4vi4h.png]

[image]

I've read a lot of stuff about rotating around a fixed point, I've tried doing it with movieclips instead of sprites, I even copy pasted a [tutorial on rotation](http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/as3rotation/) and nothing works. Why does this behavior happen and how can I fix it?

Edit: Thanks everyone, all your suggestions helped me out in different ways and they were all correct so +1, I'll just choose the solution I chose to use in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sprite is rotating around it's top-left, but you don't have any graphics in top-left. The bar is rendered in (100, 100). Try this:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,6,120); // render in 0, 0
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
mySprite.x = 100; // move it 
mySprite.y = 100;
this.addChild(mySprite);
mySprite.rotation = 45;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. So when I draw a rectangle at 100,100 graphics still takes 0,0 as it's top left corner? (and I assume 0,(right side of my rectangle) as the top right?) Should I render all graphics at 0,0 and move them?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rotate it from the center, try something like:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.x = mySprite.y = 100;
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(-3,-60,6,120);
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(mySprite);
mySprite.rotation = 45;
```

Comment: I've edited it in, but I would like to rotate it about it's top left. Am I going to have to keep redrawing it with new x,y coords based off the angle just to have it rotate in place? (I eventually want to animate it)

Comment: as @taskinoor mentioned, you can set the x,y in the drawRect function to (0,0). That will draw out from the top left. However, do you want the anchor in the top left, or do you want it in the bottom left?

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating the rectangle around mySprites registration point which is the same as its x/y coordinates (currently set to 0,0). You could draw the rectangle and then move it to the correct position by setting the sprites xy.

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(-3, -60, 6, 120);
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
mySprite.x = 100;
mySprite.y = 100;
addChild(mySprite);
mySprite.rotation = 45;
```

That should work. To see how the problem was occurring, compile the below code and you'll be able to see the movement of the original bar.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i <= 45; i+=5) {
     var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
     mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.5);
     mySprite.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 6, 120);
     mySprite.graphics.endFill();
     addChild(mySprite);
     mySprite.rotation = i;
}
```